# jQuery: Global Variable Namespace Problem

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to declare a global variable in jQuery in its own namespace?

Sure, I can declare global variables with plain old JavaScript, but they will fall in the `window`'s namespace. For example, if I had a variable named `document`, it would surely overwrite the `document` object of the `window`.

Does jQuery have a hash table that lets you store any object by their name?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure why you want to use jQuery for that? You could just create your own namespace:

```
var namespace = {
    document : "Foo"
};
```

Please elaborate, if there's some need to use jQuery somehow.

Comment: I knew for a fact that JavaScript does not let you define global variables in its own namespace so I figured jQuery might have a solution like always. :D

Comment: I might misunderstand you there, but wouldn't the variable `document` in my example now be available globally through the namespace `namespace`?

Comment: Yeah it does. I was just answering your question why I wanted to use jQuery at all.

Comment: I see. Well, if you still want to use jQuery you could go with boyetboy's approach. But it has a few downsides IMO, you might override something accidentally, e.g..

Answer (score 2):

Of course you can. Create a namespace as an object and then attach it to the jQuery function.

```
(function ($) {

  $.myNamespace = {};

})(jQuery);
```

Here I've created an auto-executing anonymous function to do the work. I can then add other propertes and functions to the namespace inside this function. Also this avoids the problem of someone else renaming `$` to something else.

After this is done you can refer to your namespace as `jQuery.myNamespace`

Answer (score 2):

If the variable is something that want to associate with an element to be used later, maybe in a different routine, you could use jQuery's "data" method to store it.

e.g.

```
    :
    :

// Save original HTML content.

var old_html = $('#box').html();
$('#box').data({originalContent: old_html});

// Replace with new content.

$('#box').empty().html(new_html);

    :

// Restore original content (maybe in a different function).

var orig_html = $('#box').data('originalContent');
$('#box').empty().html(orig_html);

    :
```

I hope this is useful to you.

Regards
        Neil